Compressions and (ir)rational trace
Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a type $II_1$ factor with tracial state $\tau$ and $P$ be a projection in $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\tau(P)=1/n$ for some natural number $n.$ It is known (Ananatharaman-Popa "An introduction to $II_1$ factors") that $\mathcal{M}$ and $M_n(P \mathcal{M} P)$ are isomorphic. Can we obtain a similar result for projections with any trace $t\in\left[0,1\right]?$
Idea: Following Popa's arguments, if $$t=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2^{-n_k}$$ is the dyadic expansion of a $0\leq t\leq 1$ and by induction we construct a sequence of mutually orthogonal projections $(p_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\tau(p_k)=2^{-n_k},\,k\in\mathbb{N},$ then the projection $$p=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p_k$$ has $\tau(p)=t$ (since $\tau$ is normal). What can we say about $\mathcal{M}$ and $p \mathcal{M} p$ ?

What do you want to say about them? It is well-known and an easy exercise that $(M^s)^t = M^{st}$ (contained in the very same Ananatharaman-Popa book you cited, in fact), so $M \simeq (pMp)^{1/t}$ (when $t \neq 0$, of course). Does that count as saying something about them?

My thought was to find and isomorphism $M_m(M)\cong M_r(p M P)$ for naturals $m,,p$ but it seems unachievable at least for the irrational case.

That’s not achievable. The LHS is $M^m$ while the RHS is $M^{rt}$. If $M$ has trivial fundamental group, then they are isomorphic iff $m = rt$. So if $M$ has trivial fundamental group, then this can only happen when $t$ is rational. (More generally, the two sides are isomorphic iff $\frac{rt}{m}$ is in the fundamental group $\mathcal{F}(M)$, so this can only happen when $r$ is in $\mathbb{Q}_+ \cdot \mathcal{F}(M)$.)

@DavidGao big time. Thank you so much.
